# Join with GROUP BY and HAVING in SQL

Tags: sql, join

Supposed that I have a schema like this one.
[image]

And now I want to retreive name, address and number of books checkout of the borrowers who have at least five book checkout.

After a while, I came up with this solution as I'm fresher in Database:

```
SELECT BR.Name, BR.Address,
   Checkout.NoOfBookCheckedOut
FROM Borrower BR, (
    SELECT CardNo, COUNT(BookId) AS 'NoOfBookCheckedOut'
    FROM Book_Loans
    WHERE DateOut IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CardNo
    HAVING COUNT(BookId) >= 5
 ) AS 'Checkout'
WHERE Checkout.CardNo = BR.CardNo
```

Is my solution correct? Is there any better way to optimize this query?

Comment: Your statement is good. You first look up the limiting book loans ans then join with borrowers. That's a good appraoach. You should use up-to-date join syntax (INNER JOIN ON) instead of listing the tables comma-separated. You should use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(BookId), because you count records, not records where BookId happens to be non-null (because this is always the case). 
timo.rieber's solution is also good. Very simple and leaving it up to the dbms wether to limit by book loans first or to join first. It's a matter of taste (and sometimes of performance) which one to prefer.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I have very little knowledge about JOIN now, so I avoided to use it now. But in the next couple of days I will study about JOIN and try to rewrite this query.
Anw, I like your comment about using COUNT(*) as I think its performance is better. Thank you @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 2):

You can use inner join here

```
SELECT BR.Name, BR.Address,
   Checkout.NoOfBookCheckedOut
FROM Borrower BR
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CardNo, COUNT(BookId) AS 'NoOfBookCheckedOut'
    FROM Book_Loans
    WHERE DateOut IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CardNo
    HAVING COUNT(BookId) >= 5
 ) Checkout
ON Checkout.CardNo = BR.CardNo
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simplify your query by joining both tables without the need for the derived table.

```
SELECT
    BR.Name,
    BR.Address,
    COUNT(BL.BookId) as NoOfBookCheckedOut

FROM
    Borrower BR JOIN Book_Loans BL ON BR.CardNo = BL.CardNo

WHERE
    BL.DateOut IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY
    BR.Name,
    BR.Address

HAVING
    COUNT(BL.BookId) >= 5
```

Comment: It seems a nice query. At first, I also wrote something similar to this. However, I was confused in `GROUP BY` as I think there will be wrong results. But now, I figure it out. THank you

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your query, make sure you have proper indexes in place on columns used in join and where clauses.